# Adding LaTeX support through MathJax for github.io site

Tags: jekyll, mathjax

I'm trying to add MathJax support to my jekyll site for github.io, and I've managed to get equation support, but the website has lost all formatting. Here's my build settings:

```
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed

markdown: kramdown
```

and here's the output in a PNG, which doesn't have the minima theme.[image]

Any hints on what's going on here?

Comment: Github has a LaTeX renderer, I'm commenting since this does not respond to your question directly but might help your goal, here's an example: https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=\Huge%20Q(H)\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}H}

Comment: Does this embed nicely into the posts? Like, can I just put that as a link inside a post and have it work just fine? It also doesn't address the question of why the formatting goes away when I can get formatted equations.